# How do i call a dispatch every time a state change happens using redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using a realtime database and i want to save the state every time it changes. Is there any way to do that? Or what is the best way to do this?

Right now im calling a dispatch to update the database right after a dispatch to update the state, but sometimes my state is not updated before the save to the database happens...

```
handleAddCard = () => {
        const { text } = this.state;
        if (text) {
            this.setState({ text: "" });
            this.props.addCard(this.props.listID, text); // update board state with new card
        }
        this.props.updateBoard(this.props.board); // save board state to firebase realtime database
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Umm I don't know if I understand your problem correctly, but it seems you need to wrap the request that you are doing to your database inside a promise, after the promise response you can dispatch your action and update the store

Comment: Sorry for being a bit unclear. It's a trello board, lets take the example of adding a new card.

`handleAddCard = () => {
        const { text } = this.state;
        if (text) {
            this.setState({ text: "" });
            this.props.addCard(this.props.listID, text); // update board state with new card
        }
        this.props.updateBoard(this.props.board); // save board state to firebase realtime database
    }`


the board state is not updated with the new card before im dispatching the save to database. I'll edit the post to add the code aswell.

Comment: ok, could you show me the code behind addCard and updateBoard? you should not have problems to update first your board